# swift - notification title to string

Tags: swift, string, xcode, push-notification

I'm trying to print the notification as string, with this code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let dict = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    let title = dict["alert"]
    let message = dict["message"] as? NSString
    print ("@", title!)
    print ("@", message)
}
```

It print:

```
@ {
    title = "Germany won";
}
@ nil
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dont use NS classes in Swift unless you have to

Comment: try this let title = dict["title"]

Comment: I'd say that `title = dict["alert"]["title"]`. But in Swift 3+, don't use NSDictionary/NSString, use Swift versions if available (the one without "NS", like Dictionary, String). Also, could you give us the content of `userInfo`?

Comment: there is error when is change NSDictionary to Dictionary. 
let message = dict["title"] is still nil

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let dict = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    let title = dict["alert"] as! NSDictionary
    let message = title["title"]
    print ("@", title)
    print ("@", message!)
}
```